# Rails 3 group_by associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by, associations

I've been trying to group models in index by an associated model.

Here's what i have:

I have model location.rb

```
  belongs_to :continent
```

which belongs to Continent.rb

```
  has_many :locations
```

locations_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @locations = Location.find(:all)
  end
```

and on my Index page

```
<% @locations.group_by(&:continent_id).each do |continent, locations| %>

    <li><%= continent %></li> 
  <% locations.each do |location| %>    
    <%= location.name %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to group locations by continent. This code above works, but i just need to show the name of the continent, now it shows only the id nr.

What's the best way to do it ?
I am newbie and I know this must be easy, but I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can try just <% @locations.group_by(&:continent).each do ...

Comment: also, @locations = Location.all is better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems to me you're listing the continents, not the locations (to keep it restfull). So I would change that for the continents controller. In the continents controller:

```
def index
  @continents = Continent.find(:all)
end
```

In continents/index.html.erb:

```
<% @continents.each do |continent| %>
  <li><%= continent.name %></li> 
  <% continent.locations.each do |location| %>    
    <%= location.name %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```